# Over release a object in an dictionary that cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS error?

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, nszombie, licode

I have a object `ECClient`, it is retained by a dictionary in `ECSignalingChannel` and also by `ECRoom`.
Unfortunatly, `ECClient` crashes when it's being released.

[image]

I guess the reason it crashes is because it's released by owner (`ECRoom`) and the dictionary (a property in `ECSignalingChannel`).

Here are the places the `ECClient` is being initialized:

```
// ECSingalingChannel.m
- (void)onSocketSignalingMessage:(NSDictionary *)msg type:(NSString *)type {
   if (!signalingDelegate) {
        signalingDelegate = [_roomDelegate clientDelegateRequiredForSignalingChannel:self];
        [signalingDelegate setStreamId:message.streamId];
        [signalingDelegate setPeerSocketId:message.peerSocketId];
        [self setSignalingDelegate:signalingDelegate];
    }
}


// ECRoom.m
- (id<ECSignalingChannelDelegate>)clientDelegateRequiredForSignalingChannel:(ECSignalingChannel *)channel {
    id client = [[ECClient alloc] initWithDelegate:self andPeerFactory:_peerFactory];
    return client;
}

// ECRoom.m
- (void)publish:(ECStream *)stream {

    // Create a ECClient instance to handle peer connection for this publishing.
    // It is very important to use the same factory.
    publishClient = [[ECClient alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                           peerFactory:stream.peerFactory
                                              streamId:nil
                                          peerSocketId:nil
                                               options:[self getClientOptionsWithStream:stream]];
    //....

    // Ask for publish
    [_signalingChannel publish:options signalingChannelDelegate:publishClient];
}   


// ECRoom.m
- (void)signalingChannel:(ECSignalingChannel *)channel didRequestPublishP2PStreamWithId:(NSString *)streamId
                                                                        peerSocketId:(NSString *)peerSocketId {
    ECClient *client = [[ECClient alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                              peerFactory:_peerFactory
                                                 streamId:streamId
                                             peerSocketId:peerSocketId
                                                  options:[self getClientOptionsWithStream:self.publishStream]];
    [p2pClients setValue:client forKey:peerSocketId];
    [_signalingChannel publishToPeerID:peerSocketId signalingChannelDelegate:client];
}
```

Here is the log with NSZombie:

```
(lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x40)
    frame #0: 0x000000010257c530 WebRTC`___lldb_unnamed_symbol6507$$WebRTC + 120
    frame #1: 0x000000010260bf74 WebRTC`___lldb_unnamed_symbol11131$$WebRTC + 56
    frame #2: 0x000000010260bef0 WebRTC`___lldb_unnamed_symbol11129$$WebRTC + 116
    frame #3: 0x000000010260a444 WebRTC`___lldb_unnamed_symbol11075$$WebRTC + 12
    frame #4: 0x000000010260a424 WebRTC`___lldb_unnamed_symbol11073$$WebRTC + 60
    frame #5: 0x000000010258bf64 WebRTC`___lldb_unnamed_symbol7191$$WebRTC + 36
    frame #6: 0x000000010258e8b4 WebRTC`___lldb_unnamed_symbol7257$$WebRTC + 80
    frame #7: 0x0000000184616ef4 libobjc.A.dylib`object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148
    frame #8: 0x0000000184624990 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_destructInstance + 68
    frame #9: 0x000000018546c3f8 CoreFoundation`-[NSObject(NSObject) __dealloc_zombie] + 136
  * frame #10: 0x000000010183a67c ALCircallSDK`__destroy_helper_block_((null)=0x00000001c5c73880) at ECClient.m:245
    frame #11: 0x0000000184df0a5c libsystem_blocks.dylib`_Block_release + 152
    frame #12: 0x0000000101a0d220 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #13: 0x0000000101a11db0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1180
    frame #14: 0x0000000185407070 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
    frame #15: 0x0000000185404bc8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2272
    frame #16: 0x0000000185324da8 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
    frame #17: 0x0000000187307020 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 100
    frame #18: 0x000000018f30578c UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 236
    frame #19: 0x000000010095e630 ALDemoApp`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016f4c79b0) at main.m:14
    frame #20: 0x0000000184db5fc0 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
(lldb)
```

How can I avoid this over-release?

Comment: Did you check these hints from the Xcode Instruments documentation? - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/EradicatingZombies.html

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Thank you so much for refining the editing!
The zombie profiling wasn't really triggered.
I double I access something from different threads at the same time now. https://medium.com/@sarthak.tayade/debugging-ios-data-race-exc-bad-access-errors-using-thread-sanitizer-tsan-66821f68d7c1